# Using integers sent serially as a variable

Tags: microcontroller

I have two Arduino Uno's linked serially via XBee Series 1's. I can send the analog value from one to the other, but I'm having problems using it as a variable on the receiving end.

I'd like to use the analog value to draw a line (think of a glcd clock you set wirelessly from a different micro controller)

This is the code from the "receiving" Arduino that tries to draw a line with respect to the incoming analog value over serial wireless.

```
incomingByte = Serial.read();



int angle = map(incomingByte,80,180,0,180);

itoa(incomingByte,ang,10);

x = (11*cos(radians(angle))+64);
y = (-11*sin(radians(angle))+50); 

glcd.drawstring(0,0,ang);
glcd.drawcircle(64,60,20,BLACK);
glcd.drawline(64,60,x,y,BLACK);
```

Nothing on the glcd changes despite the fact that it is recieving the analog value over wireless serial

Comment: What is being input??  A single digit between 0 and 9?  Can you just print incomingByte and ang to the standard output just to make sure you're getting in what you think you're getting in?  Those little debugging steps are key to figuring out problems like this.

Comment: Just to clarify...your question has nothing to do with serial transmission, does it? You say that "it is recieving [sic] the analog value". Your problem is only in the software, is that correct?

Comment: Joe, it clearly has to do with the encoding or decoding for serial transmission.  We'll probably need to see the sending side code as well to figure out what is wrong, which may well be a data representation problem.

Comment: First step would be to put a breakpoint or print statement when you get incomingByte and see what you're receiving. At the moment we have no idea if you're getting the right thing at the top of the code, without that the rest is irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnU Breakpoint is hard on Arduino, and print for debugging also hard as usually the XBee shields connect to the only UART.

Comment: Temporarily adding transmit-only soft serial might be worthwhile for debug messages, though the problem is likely conceptual.

Comment: Can you remove the xbee and send a known value into the port? I deliberately know nuffink about *duinos, but am trying to approach this in a logical manner - 1st question is "are you starting with something sane?" Geometrikal's answer below asks a similar question - are you checking the UART actually has something ready to be read? I assumed you were, but now I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have it in your code snippet, so try check for available bytes first:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    int angle = map(incomingByte,80,180,0,180);
    itoa(incomingByte,ang,10);    

    x = (11*cos(radians(angle))+64);
    y = (-11*sin(radians(angle))+50); 

    glcd.drawstring(0,0,ang);
    glcd.drawcircle(64,60,20,BLACK);
    glcd.drawline(64,60,x,y,BLACK);
}
```